# sharp installation failed (npm) while installing cordova-res and sharp packages in linux

Tags: android, linux, ionic-framework, npm, sharp

I have installed node and npm latest version in ubuntu 20.04 and debian buster.
I already installed libvips and glib packages packages from the apt in linux

---

```
/usr/include/vips/vips8:35:10: fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib-object.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sharp.target.mk:129: Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova-res/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-42-lowlatency
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova-res/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v10.21.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.25.4 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.25.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-25T14_48_56_334Z-debug.log
```

---

If anyone know please answer. How can i add *glib-object.h* to the vips directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now It's fixed by changing required version (supported old nodejs version). Using nvm you can switch between versions easily without uninstalling current version. **Many packages in node, does not support up-to-date (latest) versions. So you have to migrate to older one instead.** even it failes install **prebuild** via package manager(npm).

Answer (score 0):

1. brew install pkg-config
2. Now you need to install libvips from source
3. Download and extract the latest version from https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases
4. cd to the extracted folder
5. ./configure
6. make
7. sudo make install
8. npm i -g cordova-res

Answer (score 0):

please note if this is about ionic installation capacitor-assets replaced cordova-res .
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets